# Is there a way to match cells across multiple columns/rows in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Here's a spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JKA-HyWQXr8ARTQite9ccPXl9PwsUgpfMK_y3tqdCuE/edit?usp=sharing

So I need a formula that can identify the same text across multiple column and crossmatch it with the other rows - columns A, B, C, D (symbol, call/put, exp, and strike). I typed out in the spreadsheet what the formula should output but I'll display it here too:

AAL Call 1/21/2022  25

ABBV Call 1/21/2022 120

So the output is the above because there's at least two of the same text in columns A, B, C, and D. Hope this makes sense!

Comment: It could be a simple Vlookup if you add a helper column which add the columns like =A&B&C&D. You could also use a Pivot Table.

Comment: Sorry I don' understand. I am not familiar enough with excel/sheets to understand how to  do this.

Comment: Do you have a formula you're working on? What research did you do up to this point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=FILTER(A3:D13, 
 COUNTIFS(A3:A13&B3:B13&C3:C13&D3:D13, 
          A3:A13&B3:B13&C3:C13&D3:D13, 
          ROW(A3:A13), "<="&ROW(A3:A13))>1)
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(A3:D13, 
 COUNTIFS(A3:A13&B3:B13&C3:C13&D3:D13, 
          A3:A13&B3:B13&C3:C13&D3:D13, 
          ROW(A3:A13), "<="&ROW(A3:A13))>1))
```

Comment: Hey this worked! There is one problem I noticed. If there's 3 of the same criteria (i.e. if row 5 and 6 had the same values in for example row 14, the formula will display that result again for a second time. Any way around this?

Comment: Consider providing reference/explanation regarding the formulas you use.

Comment: @Iamblichus https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

So you want just the rows that are repeats of columns A-D, but not necessarily E? Essentially the opposite of `UNIQUE`?

The first thought that comes to mind is to kind of brute force it with the use of helper columns. Something like the below should work:

1. Use `=TEXTJOIN(",",1,A3:D3)` in an adjacent column
2. In another column, use something that will check for duplicates, maybe `=MATCH(F3, F4:F12, 0)`
3. Highlight the whole data frame and put on a filter (above the formula bar on the right). Then filter the second helper column to exclude `#N/A`'s.

I am sure there is something more elegant, but that process does the trick.
[image]